# I have a React Client and Jetty Server, i want to build an interface between these two so that i can pass my CORS headers.How to do this?

Tags: reactjs, interface, jetty, client-server, restful-architecture

I have already tried setting headers in Jetty server and failed,hence want to pass headers via an interface.Is that possible?

Things which i have tried before and the response i'm getting are as below

Error Message:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/virtualviewer/AjaxServlet: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.
```

React Client is running on http://localhost:8081 and Jetty Server on http://localhost:8080

Request Headers

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; 
q=0.01 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;
q=0.9 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 163 Content-Type: 
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
charset=UTF-8 Host: localhost:8080 Origin: http://localhost:8081 Referer: 
http://localhost:8081/Virtual_Viewer_Main/ User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 
(Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers

```
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.4.5.v20170502)
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=node0luc0i4tqevo11ruk3704zx6sh2.node0;Path=/virtualviewer
```

Jetty Server CORS filter that i have used in web.xml file.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have also embedded  jetty servlet (jetty-servlets-9.4.5.v20170502) and jetty util (jetty-util-9.4.5.v20170502) in SnowboundJettyServer/webapps/virtualviewer/WEB-INF/lib path.

Although the CORS plugin renders the result, how to do it by passing only headers?( I don't want to use CORS plugin).

Comment: This question is confusing.  "React Client is running on http://localhost:8081" is seemingly contradictory, the URL means it's a Server.

Comment: I'm doing the same, where exactly is your web.xml located in the directory structure? Where exactly is your WEB-INF folder in comparison to your app.js?